# What does &* combined together do in Rust?

Tags: rust, syntax

I was reading through the book section about `String`s and found they were using `&*` combined together to convert a piece of text. The following is what it says:

```
use std::net::TcpStream;

TcpStream::connect("192.168.0.1:3000"); // Parameter is of type &str.

let addr_string = "192.168.0.1:3000".to_string();
TcpStream::connect(&*addr_string); // Convert `addr_string` to &str.
```

In other words, they are saying they are converting a `String` to a `&str`. But why is that conversion done using both of the aforementioned signs? Should this not be done using some other method? Does not the `&` mean we are taking its reference, then using the `*` to dereference it?

Comment: I think now you can do this `&addr_string`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

**In short**: the `*` triggers an explicit deref, which can be overloaded via [`ops::Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html).

---

#### More Detail

Look at this code:

```
let s = "hi".to_string();  // : String
let a = &s;
```

What's the type of `a`? It's simply `&String`! This shouldn't be very surprising, since we take the reference of a `String`. Ok, but what about this?

```
let s = "hi".to_string();  // : String
let b = &*s;   // equivalent to `&(*s)`
```

What's the type of `b`? It's `&str`! Wow, what happened?

Note that `*s` is executed first. As most operators, the dereference operator `*` is also overloadable and the usage of the operator can be considered syntax sugar for `*std::ops::Deref::deref(&s)` (note that we recursively dereferencing here!). `String` *does* overload this operator:

```
impl Deref for String {
    type Target = str;
    fn deref(&self) -> &str { ... }
}
```

So, `*s` is actually `*std::ops::Deref::deref(&s)`, in which the `deref()` function has the return type `&str` which is then dereferenced again. Thus, `*s` has the type `str` (note the lack of `&`).

Since `str` is unsized and not very handy on its own, we'd like to have a reference to it instead, namely `&str`. We can do this by adding a `&` in front of the expression! Tada, now we reached the type `&str`!

---

`&*s` is rather the manual and explicit form. Often, the `Deref`-overload is used via automatic deref coercion. When the target type is fixed, the compiler will deref for you:

```
fn takes_string_slice(_: &str) {}

let s = "hi".to_string();  // : String
takes_string_slice(&s); // this works!
```

Answer (score 31):

In general, `&*` means to first dereference (`*`) and then reference (`&`) a value. In many cases, this would be silly, as we'd end up at the same thing.

However, Rust has [*deref coercions*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/deref-coercions.html). Combined with the [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) and [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html) traits, a type can dereference to a *different* type!

This is useful for `String`s as that means that they can get all the methods from `str`, it's useful for `Vec<T>` as it gains the methods from `[T]`, and it's super useful for all the smart pointers, like `Box<T>`, which will have **all the methods** of the contained `T`!

Following the chain for `String`:

```
String --deref--> str --ref--> &str
```

> Does not the `&` mean we are taking its reference, then using the `*` to dereference it?

No, your order of operations is backwards. `*` and `&` associate to the right. In this example, dereferencing is first, then referencing.

> I think now you can do this `&addr_string`

(from a comment)

*Sometimes*, this will do the same thing. See [What are Rust's exact auto-dereferencing rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28519997/155423) for the full details, but yes, a `&String` can be passed to a function that requires a `&str`. There are still times where you need to do this little dance by hand. The most common I can think of is:

```
let name: Option<String> = Some("Hello".to_string());
let name2: Option<&str> = name.as_ref().map(|s| &**s);
```

You'll note that we actually dereference *twice*:

```
&String -->deref--> String --deref--> str --ref--> &str
```

Although this case can now be done with `name.as_ref().map(String::as_str);`