# Match expects &Result when I want to use Result

Tags: rust

I'm using Rust 1.15 nightly and have some code with an iterator over `std::io::Result<std::fs::DirEntry>` named `dir_contents_iterator` that I'm trying to partition based on whether each `DirEntry` corresponds to a file or a folder (with `Err` values sorted into the file list):

```
let (dir_list, file_list): (Vec<std::io::Result<DirEntry>>, Vec<std::io::Result<DirEntry>>) =
    dir_contents_iterator.partition(|entry_result| {
        match entry_result {
            Ok(entry) => {
                entry
                    .file_type()
                    .and_then(|file_type| Ok(file_type.is_dir()))
                    .unwrap_or(false)
            },
            Err(_) => false
        }
    });
```

This code fails to compile with the following two errors:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:179:13
    |
179 |             Ok(entry) => {
    |             ^^^^^^^^^ expected reference, found enum `std::result::Result`
    |
    = note: expected type `&std::result::Result<std::fs::DirEntry, std::io::Error>`
    = note:    found type `std::result::Result<_, _>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:185:13
    |
185 |             Err(_) => false
    |             ^^^^^^ expected reference, found enum `std::result::Result`
    |
    = note: expected type `&std::result::Result<std::fs::DirEntry, std::io::Error>`
    = note:    found type `std::result::Result<_, _>`
```

I ended up solving my problem by rewriting my code to partition out the `Err` values first before partitioning between files and folders. This allows the match to be removed from the shown code and now it compiles. But for the sake of understanding, I'd still like to know why my original match's branch arms expect an `&Result` reference rather than accepting a `Result`, especially in the case of the second branch arm (`Err(_) => false`) which doesn't even use the value!

[Here's the problem code in the context of the project I'm working on](https://github.com/starim/shadowhack/blob/sort-picker-by-filetype/src/main.rs#L177-L187) in case I've left out any details that help explain the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this as a [MCVE](/help/mcve) (which you should have provided):

```
use std::fs::{self, DirEntry};

fn main() {
    let dirs = fs::read_dir("/tmp").expect("Nope");

    let (dir_list, file_list): (Vec<std::io::Result<DirEntry>>, Vec<std::io::Result<DirEntry>>) =
        dirs.partition(|entry_result| {
            match entry_result {
                Ok(entry) => {
                    entry.file_type()
                        .and_then(|file_type| Ok(file_type.is_dir()))
                        .unwrap_or(false)
                }
                Err(_) => false,
            }
        });
}
```

You can then [print out the type of the variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21747136/155423)

```
dirs.partition(|entry_result| {
    let () = entry_result;
    false
});
```

Which shows that `entry_result` is a `&std::result::Result<std::fs::DirEntry, std::io::Error>`.

So the answer to

> why my original match's branch arms expect an `&Result` reference

is because you are *giving it a `&Result`*!

---

For completeness, you can dereference the variable and then reference the components:

```
match *entry_result {
    Ok(ref entry) => {
```

This is redundant:

```
.and_then(|file_type| Ok(file_type.is_dir()))
```

as it can just be `map`:

```
.map(|m| m.is_dir())
```

And some more cleanup:

```
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let dirs = fs::read_dir("/tmp").expect("Nope");

    let (dir_list, file_list): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) =
        dirs.partition(|entry_result| {
            entry_result.as_ref()
                .ok()
                .and_then(|entry| entry.file_type().ok())
                .map(|ft| ft.is_dir())
                .unwrap_or(false)
        });
}
```

---

> I was under the impression that `*` and `ref` would just undo each other.

`*` and `ref` [*might* undo each other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41273041/155423), but that would only apply if they were applied to the *same value*. Here, we are pattern matching, so we take the `&Result` and pattern-match against the dereferenced value. We then take a reference to the value *inside* the `Result`, so nothing is ever moved, but we aren't dereferencing and re-referencing the same thing.

Comment: You just blew my mind with using `*entry_result` in the match and then `ref entry` in the match arm. I had no idea that worked that way. I was under the impression that `*` and `ref` would just undo each other.

Comment: @user3791276 added a bit more.